# Проблемы с загрузкой перевода drupal 7

Tags: drupal

Здравствуйте!

При импорте перевода в Drupal вылетает такая ошибка:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(temporary://drupal-7.51.ru_.po): failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in drupal_move_uploaded_file() (line 1642 of /home/media/public_html/includes/file.inc).
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpnGg9Cp' to 'temporary://drupal-7.51.ru_.po' in drupal_move_uploaded_file() (line 1642 of /home/media/public_html/includes/file.inc).
>
> File upload error. Could not move uploaded file.
>
> File to import not found.

Как решить такую проблему?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно такая проблема может быть связана с временной папкой, либо же с правами, попробуйте выполнить такие действия:

1. Создайте новый временный каталог
2. Выставить на папку права 777 (Это если на сервере, а не на локалке)
3. Перейти по пути:
   Конфигурация - Мультимедиа - Файловая система
   (admin/config/media/file-system) прописать новый/правильный путь к
   папке

Не забудьте также выставить 777 на папку  `/sites/default/files/languages`

Comment: Спасибо, сработало...) проблема после переноса сайта с локала на хост...